# Change text alternativly on button click

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox and it contains a value as "hello".I have another button,when I click on a button the text Should be changed to "not hello" and If I again click it should change to "no hello" and this process is going on..Alternatively, NOt & no should be added.I have no success to do this.

Please check my code

```
$('#negate a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var opinionWord = $('input[name="opinion-word"]').val();
    if (/no/i.test(opinionWord)) {
        opinionWord = opinionWord.replace('no ','');
        opinionword = opinionWord.substr(opinionWord.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        alert('f');
        $('input[name="opinion-word"]').val("not "+opinionWord);
    }
    else {
        opinionWord = opinionWord.replace('not ','');
        opinionword = opinionWord.substr(opinionWord.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        alert(opinionword);
        $('input[name="opinion-word"]').val("no "+opinionWord);
    }
});
```

Comment: add your codes to jsfiddle and share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, you just forgot that `not` is including the letters `no`. so just check previously for the `not`:

```
$('#negate a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var opinionWord = $('input[name="opinion-word"]').val();
    if (/not/i.test(opinionWord)) {
        opinionWord = opinionWord.replace('not ','');
        opinionword = opinionWord.substr(opinionWord.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        alert('f');
        $('input[name="opinion-word"]').val("no "+opinionWord);
    }
    else {
        opinionWord = opinionWord.replace('no ','');
        opinionword = opinionWord.substr(opinionWord.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        alert(opinionword);
        $('input[name="opinion-word"]').val("not "+opinionWord);
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/5p8c31Lc/